# Change URL but do not redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

If I want to change the visible URL of `/test.php` to just `/test` but still load the contents of `/test.php` how would I do that using `.htaccess` and `RewriteRule`?

So if the user types either `/somespecificfile.php?v=1` or `/abc?v=1`

1. they should see in the URL `/abc?v=1`
2. but the file `/somespecificfile.php?v=1` should be read from the server

I tried this and instantly got ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

```
RewriteRule ^somespecificfile\.php$ abc [R,QSA]
RewriteRule ^abc$ somespecificfile.php [L,QSA]
```

when I leave just the first line I get a 404 since `abc` doesn't really exist of course..

When I just leave the second line it partially works - I type `/abc` and `/somespecificfile.php` will be loaded and the URL remains `/abc` - but when I type `/somespecificfile.php` it also loads but the URL will not change to `/abc` .. because of course there's no instruction for it to do so..

Comment: i don't just want to remove the extension, I want to redirect and change the url /example1.php to /test so if user types /test or example1.php the same file should be loaded from server: (example1.php) and the same url should appear : /test

Comment: That is our framework routing.

Comment: Why do you need this, what would make the user "type example1.php" in the first place? If you needed to redirect existing links, that are set somewhere out of your control (on other websites), that would be a common scenario. But why would your users just by "typing" what appears to be random script names ...?

Comment: Rewriting configure on the .htaccess level "loops", until no rules match any more - that's why you are getting the too many redirects error, because after you internally rewrote the request to `somespecificfile.php`, the whole thing starts again from the top. Try using the `E` flag instead of `L` on that second rule.

Comment: I tried using E instead of L still same error too many redirects, the old link is used in emails since 10 years ago.. it has to work still.. just when its accessed it should display the new link but load the old file .. I did not think this would be so difficult ...

Comment: I assume @CBroe meant the `END` flag, not the `E` flag.

Comment: yes that seems to work.. I will answer it like that

Answer (score 1):

thanks to arkascha's comment I found the answer:

```
#this tries to load abc when both test.php and abc are accessed, and on its own will give 404 since test.php is the physical file
RewriteRule ^test\.php$ abc [R,QSA]
#this loads test.php when abc is accessed but leaves abc in the url and works in combination with the previous line
RewriteRule ^abc$ test.php [END,QSA]
```

Comment: This won't work as written. You need a slash prefix on the _substitution_ string in the first rule (ie. `/abc`) otherwise it will result in a malformed redirect (unless you also have a `RewriteBase /` directive earlier in file - but for external redirects it is recommended to be explicit and include the slash prefix for readability/maintainability). You should also include the `L` (or `END` - it doesn't matter) flag on the first rule, otherwise the request is going to be rewritten back to `test.php` before the redirect occurs. The `QSA` flag is not required on either rule here.